# Searching for an example of AWS S3 multipart file upload, Java 2 sdk

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Been searching different websites, including AWS itself and StackOverlow, for full examples or code snippets of doing a multipart file upload using the Java 2 AWS sdk (to an s3 bucket)  Found a small example at [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html)   But the data source in the example seems to be a randomized byte buffer instead of a large local file  (which in my case is 3 GB) Before striking out on my own, was hoping there'd be an example out there of doing the multipart upload by iterating over the parts of a file.  My stackoverflow search terms were "aws s3 multipart upload java 2". Closest I came to a recent example was javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75738475/aws-s3-multipart-upload-javascript-sdk) at stackoverflow . I might be able to use that as my "pseudocode"

Comment: Can you not use the [`s3.transfer.TransferManager `](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html) to manage the multipart upload for you?

Comment: Good point. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207720/multipart-upload-using-aws-java-sdk-hangs-at-99), I assumed Java 2 sdk no longer had transfer manager. Which would be dumb.  Finally located an example at [aws] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html).  Thanks!